# How can i subtract one hh.mm format time(which is decimal) from another?

Tags: c#, sql

I have 4 records in an SQL database. Which has 2 colums hours1 and hours2

- Record1 : hours1- 1.00,hours2- 1.00
- Record2 : hours1- 9.00,hours2- 5.30
- Record3 : hours1- 9.00,hours2- 9.00
- Record4 : hours1- 3.00,hours2- 3.00

So here I got the sum of these colums as :

```
SUM of column1 : 22.00
SUM of column1 : 18.30
```

These are decimal but I consider it as time.

Now I want to subtract column2 sum from column1 sum i.e.

```
22.00 - 18.30
```

So I will get `3.7` which is wrong because I considered as a time.

I want final answer as : 3.30 (justification for requirement : so when I add this result to 18.30 (18.30+3.30 which is 21.60 = 22.00 hours as 60 minute = 1 hour) I got total 22.00).

Can anyone help me how to get `3.30` as result? I cant use TimeFormat.

Comment: If you're storing times as decimals (don't), then don't save thirty minutes as `.3` but as `.5`...

Comment: To get time values you can convert the decimal to time and then do the calculation and then convert back to decimal.

Comment: I have large amout of data already stored as decimal so i cat convert it back to datetime

Comment: Then convert your data first. You can't do calculations expecting correct results on incorrect numbers.

Comment: I cant because my application is too large to be changed for this conversion.

Comment: No application is too large to be changed, just means it will take longer. Also correct results are better than incorrect ones because of a lazy programmer

Comment: If you don't want to alter your data, then you're screwed. There's no way to know whether a result of `3.0` from your sum means `2.0` + `1.0` (three hours) or `0.3`+`0.3`+`0.3`+`0.3`+`0.3`+`0.3`+`0.3`+`0.3`+`0.3`+`0.3`... (ten half hours, i.e. five hours).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone said in the comments: conversion is needed, and it must be done before summing takes place.

Here is how:

```
var times1 = new decimal[] { 1.00m, 9.00m, 9.00m, 3.00m };
var times2 = new decimal[] { 1.00m, 5.30m, 9.00m, 3.00m };

var hours1 = ActualHours(times1).Sum(); // using System.Linq;
var hours2 = ActualHours(times2).Sum();
var diff = hours1 - hours2;

var result = "Actual: hours1 = " + hours1 +
                   ", hours2 = " + hours2 +
                   ", diff   = " + diff + "\r\n" +
            "Printed: hours1 = " + Print(hours1) +
                   ", hours2 = " + Print(hours2) +
                   ", diff   = " + Print(diff);
```

Methods used:

```
public IEnumerable<decimal> ActualHours(params decimal[] values)
{
    foreach (var v in values)
    {
        var t = Math.Truncate(v);
        yield return t + (v - t) / 0.6m;
    }
}

public string Print(decimal v)
{
    var t = Math.Truncate(v);
    return (t + (v - t) * 0.6m).ToString("0.00");
}
```

Output:

```
Actual: hours1 = 22.0, hours2 = 18.5, diff = 3.5
Printed: hours1 = 22.00, hours2 = 18.30, diff = 3.30
```

Comment: Can you explain how ActualHours() and Print() works?

Comment: Exactly what is so hard to understand? Have you tried debugging and monitoring a couple of variables in Watches, that should make it clear?

Comment: I understand it fully Peter B. first i tried it without debugging thats why i was little bit confused but after debugging i fully understand it.